# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './package' in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, cheerio

I'm using `Angular 6` and [scraperjs](https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs).

and in my component file, used the code given in the example like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import scraperjs from 'scraperjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-express',
  templateUrl: './express.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./express.component.css']
})
export class ExpressComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.aliExpress();
  }

  aliExpress() {
    console.log('loaded ali express');

    scrapperjs.StaticScraper.create('https://news.ycombinator.com')
      .scrape(function ($) {
        return $('.title a').map(function () {
          return $(this).text();
        }).get();
      }).then(function (news) {
      console.log(news);
    });
  }

}
```

but it is giving error as

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/cheerio/index.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './package' in '/home/user/code/angular/ali-express/node_modules/cheerio'
```

Comment: You are trying to load a module using `require()` at run-time. There has to be a configured module loader that knows where to load files from. The default `require()` created by WebPack will only map to modules that exist in the bundles. Either make sure they are added to the bundles. Configure a different loader (like SystemJS) or use `import`.

Comment: I used `import scraperjs from 'scraperjs';` at top and removed `require`, still same error.

Comment: Can you try installing cheerio manually. `npm install --save-dev cheerio`

Comment: I tried that too. still same issue

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
npm install
```

command to install dependent packages.
I think dependent packages are not properly installed.

Comment: all packages are installed. I run it multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Remove the nodeModules from your solution folder structure and then try to install 
npm-install

Answer (score 0):

You are using `require()` to load the file which is not the standard way of loading a file in Angular.
Here, it tries to load at runtime but can't find it.

Please try loading it with import. If you still can't , try loading it in `main.ts`. I am not sure but I loaded the hammerjs same way.

Comment: updated question with import statement. still same error.

Comment: Just try import 'scrapperjs' in main.ts